# print Jmeter Bean shell script results in Jenkins Console Output?

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

How to print Jmeter Bean shell script results in Jenkins Console Output ,like if i'm executing multiple scenarios in Jmeter using Rest Services,then i want to print Test scenarios name,expected results,test results status(PASS/FAIL) in Jenkins Console Output.

Any one please help me ,how to achieve this task using Jmeter+Jenkins.

My Beanshell Script:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

cardNo=vars.get("cardno");
scenario = vars.get("Scenario");
Amount = vars.get("Amount");
transaction_ID=vars.get("transactionID");
Response_mes = vars.get("resmes");

Response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
Result = "FAIL";

if(Response.contains("SUCCESS"))    
    Result = "PASS";
f = new FileOutputStream("E:\\ApacheJmeter\\TestResults\\Test_Results.csv",true);
p=new PrintStream(f);
this.interpreter.setOut(p);
p.println(cardNo+","+Amount+","+scenario+","+transaction_ID+","+Response_mes+","+Result);

f.close();
p.close();
```

Comment: any reason you want to craft it, as opposed to using an existing plug-in, e.g.: http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/Reporting.html ?

Comment: Please try with log.info() or System.out.println(); It gives the message in the console.

Comment: I m looking for the same solution , jenkins performance plugin needs an xml or csv to parse the results , i don t want to keep this files on the server or even generate it , i want to write a text so jenkins can parse the output text and set the exit i want. log.info() does not work on non gui mode